# Finding path, the sum of whose numbered edges is 48

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph with vertices $\{1,\dots,10\}$. Two vertices $a,b$ have an edge if $a\mid b$ or $b\mid a$. Find a path in $G$ so that the sum of the corners in the path equals 48.

I solved this using "brute force", $9-3-6-2-8-4-1-10-5$, but is there a more efficient way? In particular one that doesn't rely on drawing the graph in a clever way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get a sum of 48, since $ 1 + 2 + \ldots + 10 = 55 $, the numbers which you miss must have a sum of 7.

Assume that we miss the number 7, then there are a few paths that we can take.

$$ 9- 3 - 6 - 2 - (8,4) - 1 - (5,10 ) $$

Where $(a,b)$ means it doesn't matter which vertex you chose to visit first. [Note: I have not checked if there are other solutions.]

Are there solutions where we miss other numbers?
We can't miss $\{1,6\} $ nor $\{1,2,4\}$, since $7$ must connect to 1.
If we miss $\{2,5\}$, then both 10 and 7 can only be connected to 1, which makes our path too short.
If we miss $\{3, 4\}$, then 8 and 6 can both only be connected to 1 and 2. However, 7 still needs to connect to 1, so there is no path here.
Hence, there are no other solutions.

Comment: Clever, thanks!